# Structural concurrency not cancelling child coroutines

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

```
suspend fun main(): Unit = coroutineScope{
    launch {
        while (true){
            println("infinite loop")
        }
    }

    throw Exception()
}
```

This code runs forever. Continuously printing `infinite loop`. Why doesnt structural concurrency cancel the launched coroutine?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, using `while(isActive)` should be fine.

The reason is when an Exception happened, it will propagate all the way up, and change the job state into cancelling, waiting for all child finish task, then change job state to canceled

[image]

using `while(true)` create an infinite loop, which doesn't know about job state, you can fix it by using `while(isActive)` or add `yield()` in while ture.